# Cron run schedule not running automatically on the server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, cron-task

I have this cron job code in Laravel-5.8 application:

App/Console/Commands:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Models\Hr\HrDesignation;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Exception;
use Notification;
use GuzzleHttp\Client; 
use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;


class UpdateCreateDesignation extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'updatecreatedesignations';

    protected $description = 'Update or Create Designation';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request('GET','https://api.cloudjkk.net/jkkapp/profile/all-designations', [
        'query' => ['key' => 'dddddd']
    ])->getBody();

        $clientdatas = json_decode($res->getContents(), true);    
        
        foreach($clientdatas as $clientdata)
        {        
              if ($clientdata['job_title']) {
            $designation = HrDesignation::updateOrCreate([
                'designation_name' => $clientdata['job_title']
            ],
            [
                'description'       => $clientdata['job_description'],
                'company_id'        => 1,          
            ]); 
        }
        }

    } 
}
```

For the schedule, I have this code in the kernel which is supposed to run by 1:00a.m. every day

kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\UpdateCreateDesignation',
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {       
        $schedule->command('updatecreatedesignations')
                ->dailyAt('01:00'); 
                                                                                                     
    }

    protected function commands()
    {

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

I observe that the cron job is not running on the server as scheduled by 01:00.

There is no error.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a cronjob scheduled?

Comment: @RonvarderHeijden - Please how do you mean. That's that I have. From my code, see the schedule in kernel.php        $schedule->command('updatecreatedesignations')
                ->dailyAt('01:00');

Comment: "When using the scheduler, you only need to add the following Cron entry to your server ... " - [Laravel 5.8 - Task Scheduler - Introduction - Starting the Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#introduction) ... the docs are trying to tell you what you need to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel needs to run the `php artisan schedule:run` every minute. If the current time is `01:00`, that task is executed.

So you need to:

- Add a cronjob every minute `* * * * *`.
- Go to the directory `cd /path-to-your-project`
- Run the artisan command that will match the time `php artisan schedule:run`

You can test this if you add a job with `->everyMinute();`

```php
$schedule->command('increment-db-int')
    ->everyMinute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that you have enabled the scheduler in crontab

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#introduction

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: When I tried this:

> root@MyServer:/var/www/html/jkkappt# php artisan schedule:run

I got this:

> No scheduled commands are ready to run.

Comment: That's to be expected. it isn't 01:00 in morning is it lol. If you are hosting on a linux server, have you checked that you have that entry with your crontab? You can edit this with the `crontab -e` command line command

Comment: Please how do I do that

Comment: It's in my comment, `crontab -e`